# Why is thumbnail placeholder image not resized in catalog -> product -> edit page in Admin Magento 2.2.5?

Tags: magento2

I have uploaded a placeholder image in `Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Product Image Placeholders`. But the thumbnail image is not resized by default in the `catalog_prduct_edit` page in admin Magento 2.2.5.

Page image is given below:

[image]

Comment: please ask this question in magento.stackexchange, so that it could attract more attention